# Combining 2 Callback Functions into One

Tags: javascript, filter, callback

Here is the question...

"Add code to the function **eitherCallback** in the place marked **"ADD CODE HERE"** in order to achieve the desired console logs. The result of using **eitherCallback** to combine two callbacks into one callback and then passing that one callback into **filterArray** should match the results of simply passing the two callbacks into **eitherFilter** in the *previous challenge*."

Here is the *previous challenge's* solution which I know works...

```
function eitherFilter(array, callback1, callback2) {
  // ADD CODE HERE
  const newArr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (callback1(array[i]) || callback2(array[i])) {
      newArr.push(array[i]);
    }
  }
  return newArr;
}

// Uncomment these to check your work!
 const arrOfNums = [10, 35, 105, 9];
 const integerSquareRoot = n => Math.sqrt(n) % 1 === 0;
 const over100 = n => n > 100;
 console.log(eitherFilter(arrofNums, integerSquareRoot, over100)); // should log: [105, 9]
```

Here is the code given...

```
function eitherCallback(callback1, callback2) {
  // ADD CODE HERE
}

// Uncomment these to check your work!
 function filterArray(array, callback) {
   const newArray = [];
   for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
     if (callback(array[i], i, array)) newArray.push(array[i]);
   }
   return newArray;
 }
 const arrOfNums = [10, 35, 105, 9];
 const integerSquareRoot = n => Math.sqrt(n) % 1 === 0;
 const over100 = n => n > 100;
 const intSqRtOrOver100 = eitherCallback(integerSquareRoot, over100);
 console.log(filterArray(arrOfNums, intSqRtOver100)); // should log: [105, 9]
```

I am confused as to what to do. Can anyone give me some tips? I do not know how to even start to answer it!

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need much - all you need is to make `eitherCallback` a higher-order function that takes the two callbacks as initial argument, and executes and returns the logic you're carrying out here:

```
callback1(array[i]) || callback2(array[i])
```

Like:

```js
const eitherCallback = (callback1, callback2) => x => callback1(x) || callback2(x);

// Uncomment these to check your work!
 function filterArray(array, callback) {
   const newArray = [];
   for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
     if (callback(array[i], i, array)) newArray.push(array[i]);
   }
   return newArray;
 }
 const arrOfNums = [10, 35, 105, 9];
 const integerSquareRoot = n => Math.sqrt(n) % 1 === 0;
 const over100 = n => n > 100;
 const intSqRtOrOver100 = eitherCallback(integerSquareRoot, over100);
 console.log(filterArray(arrOfNums, intSqRtOrOver100)); // should log: [105, 9]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Could you help me understand what the 'x' is doing? Is it somehow passed in? is it basically equal to the 'n' used in integerSquareRoot and over100 ? Is there a good resource you could point me to which could explain it? Thanks again!

Comment: It's just an argument to the function. Your task is to make a function that returns a function, and the returned function should take an argument, the item to test - so that's what it does.

Comment: Thanks. I'll play around with it more and research to try and understand better.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try:

```
function eitherCallback(callback1, callback2) {
  // ADD CODE HERE
  return (element, i, array) => {
   //element representing array[i] 
    return callback1(element, i, array) || callback2(element, i, array);
  }
}
```

The idea is for eitherCallback to return a truly value for either callback called within the function.  Also, I believe the "x" in the previous solution from certain performance represents the arguments array[i], i and array.  It's just a cleaner way to write it out with x instead of having to repeat it all.  Keeping things DRY.